# Cheap / free "Look and Feel" frameworks for web applications

Tags: html, templates, user-interface, usability

Usually I'm fortunate enough to work with really good designers. They take care of the look and feel for all of the web applications / sites I build.

In the past when I've done cheap or free work for people for projects I'm interested in, I've used a template from templatemonster or similar.

I want to get involved with quite a large internal application to support a friends business, the usual brochure-ware templates that are available won't be suitable because this application is all about data access.

Obviously usability is paramount and I don't have the skills to produce a nice usable interface, neither do we have the money to pay for custom work. Are there any projects which look to provide usable web templates more designed for large forms, pages of data grids, charts etc. I don't need something that is graphically cutting edge, I just need consistent, usable, easy to apply templates.

I've looked at Ext.js which has themed components, but, even with a bunch of pretty house bricks, I can't design a good looking house :)

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: What platform are you running on? PHP, ASP.NET, Rails, Java?

Comment: I'm running PHP but it's almost incidental. I don't need an installable app, I just need a collection of example / template HTML that I can use.

Answer (score 6):

[Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/designs/browse/) is a reasonable place to check.

If you're on Rails, [Baseapp](http://www.opensourcerails.com/projects/15194-BaseApp) is worth looking at, if you like the 37 Signals look.

You could also try [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) or [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) JS frameworks.

You are going to struggle finding out-of-the-box 'usability', though. Knowing where, and how, to place various elements in order to make a cohesive whole is a skill, rather than something that comes in template form. As you say, you can have a bunch of pretty bricks, but you still need a good brick-layer to make use of them. But nevertheless, the above links may help.

Answer (score 4):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) should be the latest answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

You could use [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), its got fairly reasonable API and is VERY complete.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but, I fear YUI is a library of components, I really need something that pulls all those components together with an over-arching design.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php) you can find a nice comparison about responsive frameworks. In my personal experience, I've worked with Twitter Bootstrap on several projects and like it. Since I've used the other frameworks so extensively I cannot (or should not) say it's the best, but at least it fits my requirements and I find pleasing to work with it.

With a simple web search you'll find a lot of themes (free and paid ones), pick what best fits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)?

Comment: That's a good question - I always saw these types of developments as being about delivering portal style applications. News, Shops, Image Gallery, Forums, etc. Can they really support custom data-tables with CRUD, business/domain logic?

Andrew